# Regarding SQL Server order by with select distinct

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I am getting error on this query

```
select 
    distinct convert(varchar (12),date,105) as Mydate,count(itemcount)
from
    Productiontbl 
group by
    date
order by
    cast(run_date as date) desc
```

> error :- ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT
>   DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below link and understand the order of a query execution.

https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

You are trying to `order by` a column which does not exist in your `select`.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your `SELECT DISTINCT` is not returning something that looks like what you indicate in your `ORDER BY`. You can't `ORDER BY cast(run_date as date)` if that is not in your `SELECT DISTINCT` list.

Answer (score 0):

As error says `"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."` So one of your column `convert(varchar (12),date,105) as Mydate` or `count(itemcount)` must be specify in Order by clause if you want to use order by clause in the query.